# How to change image on variant selection if we have javascript associative array

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

How to change image on variant selection if we have javascript associative array of variant_id and variant_img_src?

html Code:-

```
<select name="id" >
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if variant.available %}
  <option value="{{ variant.id }}">  {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
{% else %}
{% endfor %}
```

Javascipt Code:-

```
var images = [];
{% for variant in product.variants %}
 {% for image in product.images %}
 
     images[ {{ variant.id }}]  = "{{ variant.image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}";
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why are you posting template code when you are asking a JS question? Please click edit and `[<>]` and add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```js
const images = {
  "default": document.getElementById("img").src,
  "variant2": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/",
  "variant3": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/"
};
document.getElementById("variants").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = images[this.value];
})
```

```html
<select id="variants">
  <option value="default">Please select</option>
  <option value="variant2">Variant 2</option>
  <option value="variant3">Variant 3</option>
</select><hr/>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" id="img" />
```

Comment: What does "Is not working" mean? As you can see above it IS working according to my interpretation of your very limited information

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 
  var images = [];
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
     {% for image in product.images %}
   
         images[ {{ variant.id }}]  = "{{ variant.image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}";
     
     {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
         
</script>        

this is the java script code....

Comment: <select name="id" onchange="document.getElementById('myimage').src = images[this.value];">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
    
    {% if variant.available %}
    <option value="{{ variant.id  }}">  {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
    {%endfor%}      and this is liquid code by this i want to change picture perticular variant id..

Comment: Please post IN YOUR QUESTION the code AS RENDERED using only script and HTML! I will look in one hour or so

Comment: No you did not. You added TEMPLATING code.i you want my help, post RENDERED HTML and RENDERED JavaScript just like I did in my example!

Comment: You need `var images = {};` not `[]` - why not make it look like my code since you do not want to show me your HTML as it looks in the browser - you change my `const variants` to `const images`

Comment: You of course also need to change my `variant1` to whatever your variant.id  looks like